# Understanding the Hugging face transformers

Tags: pre-trained-model, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering, squad

I am new to the Transformers concept and I am going through some tutorials and writing my own code to understand the Squad 2.0 dataset Question Answering using the transformer models. In the hugging face website, I came across 2 different links

- https://huggingface.co/models
- https://huggingface.co/transformers/pretrained_models.html

I want to know the difference between these 2 websites. Does one link have just a pre-trained model and the other have a pre-trained and fine-tuned model?

Now if I want to use, let's say an Albert Model For Question Answering and train with my Squad 2.0 training dataset on that and evaluate the model, to which of the link should I further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would formulate it like this:
The second link basically describes "community-accepted models", i.e., models that serve as the basis for the implemented Huggingface classes, like BERT, RoBERTa, etc., and some related models that have a high aceptance or have been peer-reviewed.

This list has bin around much longer, whereas the list in the first link only recently got introduced directly on the Huggingface website, where the community can basically upload arbitrary checkpoints that are simply considered "compatible" with the library. Oftentimes, these are additional models trained by practitioners or other volunteers, and have a task-specific fine-tuning. Note that al models from `/pretrained_models.html` are also included in the `/models` interface as well.

If you have a very narrow usecase, you  might as well check and see if there was already some model that has been fine-tuned on your specific task. In the worst case, you'll simply end up with the base model anyways.